# i want filltering used re.fucntion or pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
ze = analysis_data[~analysis_data['name'].str.contains("&|!|@|~|%|\^|\*|\(|\)|_|\=|\+|\?|<|>|{|}|[|]|:|;|/|\'|\"")]

print(ze)
```

The problem is to exclude fields that contain characters `other than numbers, characters, spaces, #, , . and -` in the name column.

I used the coding above.

But it looks messy. I'd like to make it cleaner.

Comment: What characters do you want to exclude?

Answer (score 0):

Is it good enough - **alphanumeric characters** white **spaces** and ***'.#-_'***.

If you do not want ***'_'*** you could replace **'\w'** with ***'a-zA-Z0-9'*** or ***'a-zA-Z\d'***.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['ab c', 'abc123.# -', '%sdfas', '$dsfa']})

pattern = r'^[\s\w.#-]*$'
df = df.loc[df.test.str.contains(pattern), :]

>>> 0   ab c
    1   abc123.# -
```